# How extract attachments in outlook emails into download folder

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I'm trying to download emails that users saved in download folder.

I take the path but when i try to open the email file i get errors.
The error: `WinError 2`

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

c = "c:\\Download"

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

for f in os.listdir(c):
    os.starfile(f)
    excel = f.Attachments
```

Comment: c is the download folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing t on `os.starfile`, should be `startfile`

and

```
os.startfile(f) #  You are missing the path
```

so try

```
os.startfile(c + "\\" + f)
```